# how to Setting VIEWTABLE to show column names in SAS?

Tags: sas

**Problem Description:**
when viewing a sas table in VIEWTABLE, the header for each column is default to show column description, how do I make it show column name instead?

I am using SAS version:9.3

**What I did so far:**
I found the following solution [online](http://technologytales.com/2011/09/15/setting-viewtable-to-show-column-names-in-sas/) (This solution was tested on SAS 9.2)

```
VT SASHELP.VCOLUMN COLHEADING=NAMES
```

when I run this command I was given the following error

```
8713  VT SASHELP.VCOLUMN COLHEADING=NAMES
      --
      180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

The point and click version of the [solution](http://technologytales.com/2011/09/15/setting-viewtable-to-show-column-names-in-sas/) did not work for me either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a `dm` command, so you need to submit it to DM:

```
dm 'VT SASHELP.VCOLUMN COLHEADING=NAMES';
```

You could also assign that command (what you have, in mine just the part within the quotes) in KEYS ('keys' in the command bar).  You also can do this on a case by case basis in the VIEW menu once you've opened the dataset.

The way to do this permanently:

1. Open the Explorer (View -> Explorer)
2. Tools->Options->Explorer
3. Select Members
4. Select Table, Edit
5. Select &Open, Edit
6. Add COLHEADING=NAMES to the end of the string already present (should be something like `VIEWTABLE %8b."%s".DATA COLHEADING=NAMES` after you finish).
7. Save everything (OK to all dialog boxes).

This will only persist if save settings on exit is enabled in the preferences (tools-options-preferences) and this is not an `rsasuser` session (read-only access to user profiles).

Comment: Thanks @Joe ! the command line version did not change anything for me, except bring up SASHELP.VCOLUMN table. However the 7 step menu method worked!

Comment: The command indeed brings up the SASHELP.VCOLUMN table - that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: tried that method and it did not work exactly as the paper said when using SAS 9.4.  But it is easy to modify.  So open the file using VIEWTABLE and then issue the COLNAMES (or COLLABELS) command when running viewtable.  So the line that you want the OPEN command to run so that it always shows the NAMES is:
 
`VIEWTABLE %8b."%s".DATA ; colnames`